# Title of admission email

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I want to apply for an advertised PhD position by email not by the university website but I dont know what to include as the title of the email.
Just notice that it is not the supervisor I want to email to.
Thank you soooooo much.

Comment: Will they even permit it? I suspect you will just be directed to the website. Possibly by a secretary.

Answer (score 2):

If admissions are handed in by email, they will probably have a dedicated email address for admissions.  Just title your email with your name, the programme you are applying for, and an indication that it is an application, such as:

> Application of Shahryar Rah for the PhD programme in Unicorn Ethology

The rest doesn't matter, as soon as they start processing your application they are unlikely to record the title of your email.  All relevant information should be contained in the content of your application.